# Why would you use FormData over JSON in sending POST requests?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, forms

I haven't found a concrete answer to this question. Are there any benefits of using FormData or requests with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` over just normal JSON with `application/json`. For example in Axios requests?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on what the server is accepting, typically if you're are interacting with an API you will send over JSON, which informs the server about the type of data being sent over. If you send it via a form, the `content-type` (in the header of the request), will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So the server needs to be equipped, typically in the form of some type of middleware in order to parse it. For example, in express js, you would have something like the following,

```js
// used to parse json
app.use(express.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

Comment: Okay, so if my server can accept both, I can just do what is easier for me in the front end? I am asking from security/performance perspective

Comment: security wise it won't really matter, if your api responds with json, you may as well send json

Comment: FormData can potentially be send using a Simple Request for cross origin requests, while JSON will require a Preflight request in that case.

Answer (score 5):

A FormData object can trivially:

- Encode all the data in a `<form>`
- Encode *files* without having to manually convert them to strings
- Encode data in a format that is natively supported by common server-side environments like PHP (i.e. it will populate `$_FILES` and `$_POST`).

None of that applies to JSON.

Comment: So it seems I should use Forms if I have a more complex inputs like files?

Comment: You can add files to a formdata object manually. Forms provide semantic structure for groups of fields and allow a formdata object to slurp up the entire contents of all the fields.